# .OrderBy dinamicamente em Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

Tenho um campo `int` chamado `OrdemDosProdutosDestaque`  onde armazeno a preferência da ordem dos produtos (Meu cliente que escolhe e armazeno no banco de dados).

ex:

```
1=Aleatório
2=Preço
3=Referência
4=Categoria
etc..
```

**Model ConfigCliente**

```
[Column("int_SORT")]
    public int OrdemDosProdutosDestaque { get; set; }

    public string OrdemDestaque() {
//tentativa de transformar int em algo utilizavel
        var retorno = "";
        if (OrdemDosProdutosDestaque == 1)
        {
            retorno = "Aleatório";
        }
        else if (OrdemDosProdutosDestaque == 2)
        {
            retorno = "Valor";
        }
        //etc

        return retorno;
    }
```

Depois lá na minha *controller* eu quero ordenar os produtos de acordo com a opção do cliente.

Algo como:

```
IQueryable<produto> produtos = db.produtos
                        .Include(i => i.Cidade)
                        .Where(w => w.ClienteId == IDC && w.EstaAutorizado);

            if (ImovelEmDestaque)
            {
               produtos = produtos.OrderBy(o => o.cliente.ConfigCliente.OrdemDosProdutosDestaque);
            };
```

É claro que nesse caso ainda estou enviando para o campo `int`, mas como enviar as propriedades como valor, categoria, lá da *model* Produto, ou aleatório, ou ainda se for outra *model* como fotos?

OBS: Na *Model* `Produto` criei um campo `bool TemFotos()`, assim sei facilmente se tem fotos ou não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse `Include` deveria ser assim, pelo princípio do uso de carga antecipada:

```
IQueryable<produto> produtos = db.produtos
                                 .Include(i => i.Cidade)
                                 .Include(i => i.Cliente.ConfigCliente)
                                 .Where(w => w.ClienteId == IDC && w.EstaAutorizado);
```

Só que você quer uma operação especial de `ORDER BY` em cima de uma informação que você ainda não tem. Melhor selecionar o cliente antes:

```
var cliente = db.Clientes
                .Include(c => c.ConfigCliente)
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClienteId == IDC);
```

E aí usar a `OrdemDosProdutosDestaque` com um `switch`:

```
switch (cliente.ConfigCliente.OrdemDosProdutosDestaque)
{
    case 2:
        produtos = produtos.OrderBy(p => p.Valor);
        break;
    ...
}
```

Já o aleatório no Linq to Entities precisa da lista já materializada (ou seja, depois to `ToList()`. Dá pra fazer de duas formas:

#### 1. [`.Shuffle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619/1314276)

```
if (cliente.ConfigCliente.OrdemDosProdutosDestaque == 1) {
    var lista = produtos.ToList().Shuffle();
}
```

#### 2. Guids

```
if (cliente.ConfigCliente.OrdemDosProdutosDestaque == 1) {
    var lista = produtos.ToList().OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid());
}
```

---

**EDIT**

O @TobyMosque [deu a ótima sugestão de tentar ordenar pelo `Guid` antes de materializar a lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138721/orderby-dinamicamente-em-lambda/138725?noredirect=1#comment287618_138725), e funciona:

```
if (cliente.ConfigCliente.OrdemDosProdutosDestaque == 1) {
    var lista = produtos.OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
}
```

O comando, portanto, pode ser usado no `switch`.

Comment: Cigano, acredito que o `Guid.NewGuid()` é traduzido para `NEWID()`, então o `.OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid())` se transformará em `ORDER BY NEWID()`, então deve ser possível fazer a consulta "random" sem o  `ToList()`.

Comment: Tem razão. No SQL funcionou.